# How to change the alert action title color in swift 4.x or +

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, layout

I have seen that i can only change the Alert title color using the following statement:

```
alert.setValue(NSAttributedString(string: alert.message, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 29, weight: UIFontWeightMedium), NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.red]), forKey: "attributedTitle")
```

Comment: okay what was the issue u faced

Comment: thanks Schaheer Saleem for the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to change the alert action title color:

```
let cancelAlert = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:nil)
            cancelAlert.setValue(UIColor.blue, forKey: "titleTextColor")
            alert.addAction(cancelAlert)
```

Comment: 'UIAlertActionStyle' has been renamed to 'UIAlertAction.Style' so it should be `let cancelAlert = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler:nil)
            cancelAlert.setValue(UIColor.blue, forKey: "titleTextColor")`

Comment: This code has never been supported. It may crash in any future iOS update. Don't try to access privates APIs like this.